# Getting more information about the UART

Tags: linux, debian, serial

On my desk I've got a [BPC 5070](http://arestech.com.tw/en/products/Embedded_Box_PC/bpc5070.html). I installed Debian (8.4) on it and it's working fine.

I also need to read and write from the serial ports, so I wanted to make a test and installed `minicom` and started it. I wasn't able to read/write anything on any port, using a normal cable and null modem cable.

So I executed

```
$ dmesg | grep tty
```

but the output was empty. I was hoping to see something like this

```
[    2.697479] 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

which is the output on my developer PC.

So I wanted to check the UART type:

```
$ setserial -g /dev/ttyS0 
/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
```

and it says `unkown`. So I tried ever uart type found in the man page

```
$ setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart xxx
$ cat /dev/ttyS0
cat: /dev/ttyS0: Input/output error
```

What should I do? Perhaphs I should install a firmware file that is not shipped with debian?

Comment: If the syslog has no messages, and there are no device nodes named /dev/ttyS*, then there are no serial ports available.  Since this is a PC, you should try entering the BIOS configuration page (aka setup), and look to enable/configure the serial port(s).

Comment: @sawdust: `/dev/ttyS*` are present. I think the problem is that for some reason the UART chip is not recognized by the kernel. I'll take a look in the BIOS and see if I can find anything on the serial ports.

Comment: I checked the BIOS, COM1 - COM4 were already enabled. I tried different distros (grml, ubuntu) and I even compiled a 4.7.1 kernel from scratch, I get the some problem.

Comment: You write that device nodes exist (w/o any details), yet there are no messages in the system log?!!!  Check the directory **/proc/tty/driver**.  And you need to be a lot more explicit.  E.G. in the BIOS, what are the configurations for these COM ports?  The back panel has only two connectors, and the specs states only two serial ports.  So how do you enable four ports?

Comment: `/proc/tty/driver` has only one file: `serial`. All 4 lines look like `0: uart:unknown port:000003F8 irq:4` with a different irq. I know that the panel only has 2 connectors, that doesn't mean that the main board doesn't support 4 serial lines. Anyway the BIOS has settings for COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4. You can either enable or disable them, If enabled you can set the type (rs-232, rs-423, rs-485). The `rs-485` option yields another option. I need `rs-232` only so that other option doesn't matter.

Comment: The distributor of this industrial pc installed openSuSE on it and they also had trouble with the serial ports. I guess they had the same issue as I do. It seems that I cannot fix it. I'll just buy a pl2303 usb converter, at least I have a few free USB ports there.